# Creating a calendar in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

We use a lookup table in a database for grouping weeks, months and years. Sadly the chap who created it has long since gone and the calendar runs out at the end of the year! So I really need to find a way of adding to it! Its set up with the following columns:

[image]

I'm not very good in sql(MS2008) to be honest and ive stuggeled with it, we cant set anything new up as everything is built around this!

Comment: You are saying you cannot set anything new up, so what are you trying to achieve then? You have the table already set up in your Excel-sheet, which has "unlimited" number of rows; why dont just add to it? I don't really get the problem.

Comment: im trying to add to the current table in the database, excel works fine for the date's and that but it doesnt work well with the ID's it ends up completly out.

Comment: That looks like the first two rows. Add the last few rows in the table to your post.

Comment: Seems duplicate of: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45484/how-where-to-get-date-time-calendar-data-to-store-in-a-table

Comment: its close to the other one but not a duplicate. Its more the ID's that are causing me an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do smth like this, but I don't get why your calendar starts from March?

```
declare @Date_Start date, @Date_End date

select @Date_Start = '20130101'
select @Date_End = '20131231'

;with
CTE_Dates as (
    select @Date_Start as [Date]
    union all
    select dateadd(dd, 1, [Date])
    from CTE_Dates
    where [Date] < @Date_End
),
CTE_Calendar as (
    select
        [Date],
        datename(dw, [Date]) as [Day],
        datepart(ww, [Date]) as [Week],
        datepart(mm, [Date]) as [MonthID],
        dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0) as [Month],
        datepart(yy, [Date]) as [YearID],
        dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 0) as [Year],
        datepart(qq, [Date]) as [QuarterID],
        dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()), 0) as [Quarter]
    from CTE_Dates
)
select
    row_number() over (order by [Date]) + @Start_ID - 1 as ID,
    *
from CTE_Calendar
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5174)

Comment: That's perfect! as for the march thing I have no idea either! Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts on what i can do about the ID fields? they need to increase as the weeks do. for example when i hit week 52 in a year it still needs to auto increment for the ID (week 1 in the new year would be week ID 53)